# js source maps disappears after modifying any file

Tags: coffeescript, brunch

I have a project with coffeescript and brunch.

There is following config for files concatenation:

```
files:
  javascripts:
    joinTo:
      'js/app.js': /^app(\/|\\)(?!templates)/
      'js/vendor.js': /^vendor/

  templates:
    joinTo:
      'js/templates.js': /^app\/templates/
```

When I just clone this project and build it, all works fine - I see all my source files in developer console.
Then I do some harmless modifications in any file in project (like adding a useless variable declaration or duplicating "return" statement), and strange things happens:

[image]

A builded code is valid and works fine, but there are no source maps available.

If I disable source maps at all, I still can see some wrong behaviour:

[image]

And in the same time, origin build file is absolutely valid (can't post third link, sorry): it has '//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map' line in the end, without any trailing spaces or whatever else.

Any ideas what can this be and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you create an issue on our GitHub?

Comment: Ok, it seems that brunch is not guilty. So no issue required.

Comment: The problem with broken files was somewhere in my environment.
But sometimes similar problem happens again - and only in Chrome. There are no source maps for my app.js, while maps for templates and vendor are loaded properly (and now loaded app.js file is valid). 
There is really no regularity in this: I can work entire day, and just after random refresh maps for app disappears.
What the magic is this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found where I was wrong.

First. About broken files loaded by browser.

As I noticed in comment above, the problem was in environment. My files are served by nginx, running inside Vagrant VM - and it seems, that sync between local files and VM was broken.

My solution was following:

- disable caching in VirtualBox (machine settings -> tab 'Storage' -> select controller -> uncheck 'Use Host I/O cache');
- edit nginx config and set 'sendfile off' option in 'http' section.

Not sure this is absolutely right solution, but  after this correct files was loaded by browser.

Second. About still absent maps for app.js in Chrome.

It's just my inattention. I'm using Webstorm, and periodically it proposes to enable watcher for coffeescript files I open. And if you agree (what I've accidentally did missing 'Agree' button instead of 'Dismiss'), it will compile that file at his own, creating .map and .js files alongside origin .coffee - of course, no matter to your brunch or whatever else settings. These additional files are displayed as subfolders of .coffee file, so it is very likely that you do not notice them. And exactly these files Chrome does not like. Until you remove them all, Chrome will not display any source maps, no matter to .map file created by brunch - while for FF it's not a problem.